# Apagar informações de um vetor que esta em outra classe C++

Tags: c++, classes, array

Olá, tenho uma duvida em relação a classes em C++, espero que alguém possa me ajudar. Desde já obrigado!

Estou desenvolvendo um trabalho pra faculdade em que preciso cadastrar alunos, disciplinas e notas e no final exibir alguns relatórios, tudo isso usando o conceito de classes e orientação a objetos. O programa esta 99% pronto só encontrei problemas para implementar o seguinte:

Tenho 6 classes implementadas (Não vou postar o codigo da Disciplina pois não vem ao caso):

Alunos

```
#ifndef ALUNOS_HPP_INCLUDED
#define ALUNOS_HPP_INCLUDED

#include "Bibliotecas.hpp"

class Aluno {
public:
    Aluno();

    string nome;
    string cpf;
    string bairro;
    string cidade;
    string endereco;
    string identidade;
    string estadoCivil;
    string dataNascimento;
    int numeroMatricula;
};

#endif // ALUNOS_HPP_INCLUDED
```

Cadastro Alunos

```
#ifndef CADASTROALUNOS_HPP_INCLUDED
#define CADASTROALUNOS_HPP_INCLUDED

#include "Alunos.hpp"
#include "CadastroNotas.hpp"

//class CadastroNotas;

class CadastroAlunos {
public:
    CadastroNotas cadNotas;

    Aluno alunos[100];
    int indice;

    CadastroAlunos() {indice = 0;}

    void cadastrarAlunos();
    void alterarAlunos();
    void excluirAlunos(CadastroNotas cadNotas);
    void listarAlunos();
    int pesquisar(int numMatricula);
};

#endif // CADASTROALUNOS_HPP_INCLUDED
```

Notas

```
#ifndef NOTAS_HPP_INCLUDED
#define NOTAS_HPP_INCLUDED

#include "Bibliotecas.hpp"
class Nota {
public:
    Nota();

    int codigoNota;
    int codigoMatricula;
    int codigoDisciplina;
    double media1;
    double media2;
    double media3;
    double media4;
    double mediaFinal;
    string nomeAluno;
    string nomeDisciplina;
};

#endif // NOTAS_HPP_INCLUDED
```

Cadastro Notas

```
#ifndef CADASTRONOTAS_HPP_INCLUDED
#define CADASTRONOTAS_HPP_INCLUDED

#include "Notas.hpp"
//#include "CadastroAlunos.hpp"
#include "CadastroDisciplinas.hpp"

class CadastroAlunos;

class CadastroNotas {
public:
    //CadastroAlunos cadAlunos;
    CadastroDisciplinas cadDisciplinas;

    Nota notas[100];
    int indice;

    CadastroNotas() {indice = 0;}

    void cadastrarNotas(CadastroAlunos cadAlunos, CadastroDisciplinas cadDisciplinas);
    void alterarNotas();
    void excluirNotas();
    void listarNotas();
    void excluirNotas(int numMatricula);
    int pesquisarMatricula(int pos);
    int pesquisarDisciplina(int pos);
    int comparaPosicao(int matricula, int disciplina);
    string aprovado_reprovado(int pos);
};

#endif // CADASTRONOTAS_HPP_INCLUDED
```

Nelas eu declaro meus vetores, as variaveis que tenho dentro de cada vetor e os prototipos da funções.

O programa funcionam 100%, mas falta implementar uma função que ao excluir um aluno do vetor de alunos que esta na classe Cadastro Alunos também tenho que excluir todas as notas cadastradas para este mesmo aluno, mas as notas estão em um vetor dentro de outra classe, a classe Cadastro Notas. Consigo excluir o aluno e as notas separadamente pois em cada classe tenho uma função excluir, mas de dentro da classe Cadastro Aluno não consigo apagar as notas na classe Cadastro Notas.

Minha função para exclur as notas (Ela esta no Notas.cpp onde estão minhas funções referentes as notas):

```
void CadastroNotas::excluirNotas(int numMatricula) {
    int pos = 0;
    do {
        pos = pesquisarMatricula(numMatricula);
        if(pos >= 0){
            for(int i = pos; i < indice; i++) {
                notas[pos] = notas[pos + 1];
                indice--;
            }
        }
    } while(pos >= 0);
}
```

Chamo esta função no meu arquivo Alunos.cpp em que tenho minhas funçoes para classe Aluno e Cadastro Aluno, consigo obter as informações do vetor mas não consigo altera-las. Se eu chama-la dentro do Notas.cpp onde estão minhas funçoes referentes as notas ele apaga as notas corretamente.

Como devo proceder para que consiga chamar de dentro do meu Alunos.cpp esta função e ela apague os dados do vetor de notas que esta na classe Cadastro Notas?

Se não entenderem alguma coisa ou precisarem de mais informações e só dizer.

Obrigado novamente!

**EDIT >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>**

Resolvi o problema como comentei abaixo só que minha função "excluirNotas()" que achei estar funcionando corretamente não está.

```
void CadastroNotas::excluirNotas(int numMatricula) {
    int pos = 0;
    do {
        pos = pesquisarMatricula(numMatricula);
        if(pos >= 0){
            for(int i = pos; i < indice; i++) {
                notas[pos] = notas[pos + 1];
            }
            indice--;
        }
    } while(pos >= 0);
}
```

Acontece o seguinte:

No meu vetor de notas tenho em cada posição a matricula, nomeAluno, codigoDisciplina, nomeDisciplina, media1..., essa função teria que varrer todo o vetor e onde a matricula fosse igual a pesquisada (função "pesquisarMatricula()" logo abaixo) ele copiaria as informações das posições seguintes uma posição acima e decrementaria meu índice, e voltaria a pesquisar se ainda existe uma outra posição com a matricula (posso ter mais de uma disciplina cadastrada e nota cadastrada para cada matricula).

Ela exclui todas as notas da matricula pesquisada, mas as outras matriculas ficam com dados duplicados.

Por exemplo tenho 2 alunos/matriculas com 3 disciplinas com notas cadastradas para cada um (6 posições do vetor de notas ocupadas), se eu mandar excluir o aluno/matricula 1 ele exclui todas as informações mas o aluno/matricula 2 fica com duas notas repetidas e a ultima nota cadastrada some, e ficam 4 posições ocupadas onde deviam ser só 3.

Se alguém achar onde estou errando, já fiz varias alterações mas todas geram os mesmos resultados ou muito parecidos.

Pesquisar Matricula:

```
int CadastroNotas::pesquisarMatricula(int pos) {
    for(int i = 0; i < indice; i++) {
        if (notas[i].codigoMatricula == pos)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**EDIT 2 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>**

Resolvi o problema da função "excluirNotas()" depois de muito quebrar a cabeça; acho que está correta agora (pelo menos nos meus testes estava funcionando), se alguem achar algum erro comente q eu corrigo pra ficar aqui como referência para futuras pesquisas.

```
void CadastroNotas::excluirNotas(int numMatricula) {
    for(int i = 0; i < indice; i++) {
        if(notas[i].codigoMatricula == numMatricula) {
            for(int j = i; j < indice; j++) {
                notas[j] = notas[j + 1];
            }
            i--;
            indice--;
        }
    }
}
```

Muito obrigado a todos!!!

Comment: Consegui resolver em parte o problema, alterei minha função de "void excluirAluno()" para "int excluirAluno()" me retornando depois do aluno excluído o numero da matricula e dentro do arquivo Menu.cpp onde ficam todos os menus que uso no programa, no case referente chamei duas funções a "excluirAluno()" que me retorna a matricula que uso na "excluirNotas(matricula)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A implementação está excelente, mas este é um problema de design. Você tem a opção de utilizar [composição](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) ou [herança](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)). Usando composição, a classe Aluno poderia ter objetos Nota. Sendo assim, para cadastrar ou excluir, você o faria diretamente da classe Aluno (Pois como todo Aluno guarda objetos Nota, bastaria apenas criar [*accessor* e *mutator methods*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)#Accessor.2C_mutator_and_manager_methods) de acordo). Para este caso, a abordagem de composição é mais apropriada que a de herança.

O que quero que faça é que filosofe sobre o seu projeto. Aluno e CadastroAlunos, Nota e CadastroNotas? Não seria melhor, Nota, Aluno e Sala? Todo Aluno **tem** Nota(s), toda Sala **tem** Aluno(s), e toda Escola/Universidade tem Sala(s) (Ou toda "Disciplina", no seu caso). Projetando desta maneira, seria fácil fazer o que você quer (Excluir um aluno e suas notas ao mesmo tempo, visto que ao excluir um aluno, suas notas seriam excluídas automaticamente. Ao excluir uma sala, os alunos seriam excluídos automaticamente. Ao excluir uma escola/universidade ou disciplina, todas as salas com todos os alunos e todas as suas notas, seriam excluídos automaticamente).

**>>> EDIT:**

A pedido do Luiz, hei de complementar a resposta.

Eu recriei o projeto do OP em 9 arquivos (4 headers, e 5 source files).

Resolução do problema do OP com um exemplo no arquivo **main.cpp**, em cima de minha implementação:

```
#include "disciplina.h"
#include "sala.h"
#include "aluno.h"
#include "nota.h"

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Disciplina matematica("Matematica");

    // Cadastramento de Salas por Número.

    matematica.cadastrar_sala(1, Sala());
    matematica.cadastrar_sala(2, Sala());

    Sala primeira_sala = matematica.pegar_sala(1);
    Sala segunda_sala = matematica.pegar_sala(2);

    // Cadastramento de Alunos por Matrícula.

    primeira_sala.cadastrar_aluno(11, Aluno("Isabelle"));
    primeira_sala.cadastrar_aluno(22, Aluno("Victoria"));
    segunda_sala.cadastrar_aluno(33, Aluno("Agatha"));
    segunda_sala.cadastrar_aluno(44, Aluno("Annabel Lee"));

    Aluno al1 = primeira_sala.pegar_aluno(11);
    Aluno al2 = primeira_sala.pegar_aluno(22);
    Aluno al3 = segunda_sala.pegar_aluno(33);
    Aluno al4 = segunda_sala.pegar_aluno(44);

    // Cadastramento de Notas por Código.

    al1.cadastrar_nota(6666, Nota());
    al2.cadastrar_nota(7777, Nota());
    al3.cadastrar_nota(8888, Nota());
    al4.cadastrar_nota(9999, Nota());

    /*

    Resolução do Problema do OP.

    Victoria foi uma aluna muito, muito ruim,
    E por tanto, foi excluída da sala, e junto com ela,
    Todas as suas notas...

    */

    primeira_sala.excluir_aluno(22); // Excluir por matrícula.
    cout << primeira_sala.pegar_quantidade_de_alunos(); // Confirmar que agora, na primeira sala, há apenas 1 aluno (Isabelle).

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**IMPLEMENTAÇÃO:**

- Headers

**disciplina.h**

```
#ifndef DISCIPLINA_H_INCLUDED
#define DISCIPLINA_H_INCLUDED

#include "sala.h"

typedef int numero;

class Disciplina
{
private:
    string nome;
    map<numero, Sala> salas;
public:
    Disciplina(string nome);
    ~Disciplina() {};
    string pegar_nome();
    map<numero, Sala> pegar_salas();
    Sala pegar_sala(numero n);
    void alterar_nome(string nome);
    int pegar_quantidade_de_salas();
    void cadastrar_sala(numero n, Sala sala);
    void excluir_sala(numero n);
    bool checar_se_ha_sala(numero n);
    void excluir_todas_as_salas();
};

#endif // DISCIPLINA_H_INCLUDED
```

**sala.h**

```
#ifndef SALA_H_INCLUDED
#define SALA_H_INCLUDED

#include "aluno.h"

typedef int matricula;

class Sala
{
private:
    map<matricula, Aluno> alunos;
public:
    Sala() {};
    ~Sala() {};
    map<matricula, Aluno> pegar_alunos();
    Aluno pegar_aluno(matricula m);
    int pegar_quantidade_de_alunos();
    void cadastrar_aluno(matricula m, Aluno aluno);
    void excluir_aluno(matricula m);
    bool checar_se_ha_aluno(matricula m);
    void excluir_todos_os_alunos();
};

#endif // SALA_H_INCLUDED
```

**aluno.h**

```
#ifndef ALUNO_H_INCLUDED
#define ALUNO_H_INCLUDED

#include "nota.h"

typedef int codigo;

class Aluno
{
private:
    string nome;
    string cpf;
    string bairro;
    string cidade;
    string endereco;
    string identidade;
    string estado_civil;
    string data_de_nascimento;
    map<codigo, Nota> notas;
public:
    Aluno(
        string nome="",
        string cpf="",
        string bairro="",
        string cidade="",
        string endereco="",
        string identidade="",
        string estado_civil="",
        string data_de_nascimento="");
    ~Aluno() {};
    string pegar_nome();
    string pegar_cpf();
    string pegar_bairro();
    string pegar_cidade();
    string pegar_endereco();
    string pegar_identidade();
    string pegar_estado_civil();
    string pegar_data_de_nascimento();
    map<codigo, Nota> pegar_notas();
    Nota pegar_nota(codigo n);
    int pegar_quantidade_de_notas();
    void alterar_nome(string nome);
    void alterar_cpf(string cpf);
    void alterar_bairro(string bairro);
    void alterar_cidade(string cidade);
    void alterar_endereco(string endereco);
    void alterar_identidade(string identidade);
    void alterar_estado_civil(string estado_civil);
    void alterar_data_de_nascimento(string data_de_nascimento);
    void cadastrar_nota(codigo n, Nota nota);
    void excluir_nota(codigo n);
    bool checar_se_ha_nota(codigo n);
    void excluir_todas_as_notas();
};

#endif // ALUNO_H_INCLUDED
```

**nota.h**

```
#ifndef NOTA_H_INCLUDED
#define NOTA_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class Nota
{
private:
    double media1;
    double media2;
    double media3;
    double media4;
    double media_final;
public:
    Nota() {};
    ~Nota() {};
    /*
    Métodos de cálculo de média aqui.
    */
};

#endif // NOTA_H_INCLUDED
```

- Source Files

**disciplina.cpp**

```
#include "disciplina.h"

Disciplina::Disciplina(string nome)
{
    this->nome = nome;
}

string Disciplina::pegar_nome()
{
    return this->nome;
}

map<numero, Sala> Disciplina::pegar_salas()
{
    return this->salas;
}

void Disciplina::alterar_nome(string nome)
{
    this->nome = nome;
}

Sala Disciplina::pegar_sala(numero n)
{
    return this->salas[n];
}

int Disciplina::pegar_quantidade_de_salas()
{
    return this->salas.size();
}

void Disciplina::cadastrar_sala(numero n, Sala sala)
{
    this->salas[n] = sala;
}

void Disciplina::excluir_sala(numero n)
{
    this->salas.erase(n);
}

bool Disciplina::checar_se_ha_sala(numero n)
{
    if (this->salas.count(n) > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void Disciplina::excluir_todas_as_salas()
{
    this->salas.clear();
}
```

**sala.cpp**

```
#include "sala.h"

map<matricula, Aluno> Sala::pegar_alunos()
{
    return this->alunos;
}

Aluno Sala::pegar_aluno(matricula m)
{
    return this->alunos[m];
}

int Sala::pegar_quantidade_de_alunos()
{
    return this->alunos.size();
}

void Sala::cadastrar_aluno(matricula m, Aluno aluno)
{
    this->alunos[m] = aluno;
}

void Sala::excluir_aluno(matricula m)
{
    this->alunos.erase(m);
}

bool Sala::checar_se_ha_aluno(matricula m)
{
    if (this->alunos.count(m) > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void Sala::excluir_todos_os_alunos()
{
    this->alunos.clear();
}
```

**aluno.cpp**

```
#include "aluno.h"

Aluno::Aluno(
    string nome,
    string cpf,
    string bairro,
    string cidade,
    string endereco,
    string identidade,
    string estado_civil,
    string data_de_nascimento)
{
    this->nome = nome;
    this->cpf = cpf;
    this->bairro = bairro;
    this->cidade = cidade;
    this->endereco = endereco;
    this->identidade = identidade;
    this->estado_civil = estado_civil;
    this->data_de_nascimento = data_de_nascimento;
}

string Aluno::pegar_nome()
{
    return this->nome;
}

string Aluno::pegar_cpf()
{
    return this->cpf;
}

string Aluno::pegar_bairro()
{
    return this->bairro;
}

string Aluno::pegar_cidade()
{
    return this->cidade;
}

string Aluno::pegar_endereco()
{
    return this->endereco;
}

string Aluno::pegar_identidade()
{
    return this->identidade;
}

string Aluno::pegar_estado_civil()
{
    return this->estado_civil;
}

string Aluno::pegar_data_de_nascimento()
{
    return this->data_de_nascimento;
}

map<int, Nota> Aluno::pegar_notas()
{
    return this->notas;
}

Nota Aluno::pegar_nota(codigo n)
{
    return this->notas[n];
}

int Aluno::pegar_quantidade_de_notas()
{
    return this->notas.size();
}

void Aluno::alterar_nome(string nome)
{
    this->nome = nome;
}

void Aluno::alterar_cpf(string cpf)
{
    this->cpf = cpf;
}

void Aluno::alterar_bairro(string bairro)
{
    this->bairro = bairro;
}

void Aluno::alterar_cidade(string cidade)
{
    this->cidade = cidade;
}

void Aluno::alterar_endereco(string endereco)
{
    this->endereco = endereco;
}

void Aluno::alterar_identidade(string identidade)
{
    this->identidade = identidade;
}

void Aluno::alterar_estado_civil(string estado_civil)
{
    this->estado_civil = estado_civil;
}

void Aluno::alterar_data_de_nascimento(string data_de_nascimento)
{
    this->data_de_nascimento = data_de_nascimento;
}

void Aluno::cadastrar_nota(codigo n, Nota nota)
{
    this->notas[n] = nota;
}

void Aluno::excluir_nota(codigo n)
{
    this->notas.erase(n);
}

bool Aluno::checar_se_ha_nota(codigo n)
{
    if (this->notas.count(n) > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void Aluno::excluir_todas_as_notas()
{
    this->notas.clear();
}
```

**nota.cpp**

```
#include "nota.h"

/*
Métodos de cálculo de média aqui.
*/
```

**CONCLUSÃO:**

Como o OP poderá ver, ao invés de eu incluir um número de matrícula dentro da classe Aluno, eu criei um map dentro de Sala, cujas chaves são matrículas (Assim, é possível acessar todo aluno por sua matrícula, sem incluir nenhuma matrícula dentro do Aluno em si, visto que este é um detalhe relevante apenas para a Sala). O mesmo acontece com a Sala (Disciplina tem um map cujas chaves são números), e com Nota (Aluno tem um map cujas chaves são códigos para Notas). Implementei getters e setters de acordo, e o mais importante: Ao excluir um aluno, suas notas são excluídas automaticamente, pois as notas **fazem parte** da classe Aluno, ao invés estarem separadas dela.

Enfim, espero que tenha ficado claro como composição resolve o seu problema, e como trata-se de um problema de design (Até é possível resolver o seu problema sem alterar o design, mas isso seria de uma atrocidade astronômica em nível de projeto (Seria possível, se CadastroAlunos herdasse de CadastroNotas. Assim, seria possível excluir as notas de dentro do seu Alunos.cpp)).

Comment: Ótima resposta. Concordo muito com a sua sugestão. Mas, talvez o AP tenha dificuldade em entender o que você disse apenas por texto. Se você tiver um tempinho, faça dois diagramas UML enxutos (um antes e outro depois) pra ilustrar o que quis dizer. Também seria interessante você refazer o método de exclusão, pra facilitar esse entendimento. Uma resposta assim seria ótima para ajudar não apenas ao AP, mas a outros usuários futuros com dúvidas semelhantes. :)

Comment: Pronto, @LuizVieira, está editado.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado pela resposta, vai ficar favoritada esta pagina aqui pra uso em trabalhos futuros pois este não terei tempo de alterar todo seguindo suas orientações. Consegui resolver em parte o problema, alterei minha função de "void excluirAluno()" para "int excluirAluno()" me retornando depois do aluno excluído o numero da matricula e dentro do arquivo Menu.cpp onde ficam todos os menus que uso no programa, no case referente chamei duas funções a "excluirAluno()" que me retorna a matricula que uso na "excluirNotas(matricula)". Mas estou tendo outro problema que coloquei na pergunta.